# Any SharePoint geek to comment on architecture?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

We are working with an existing SharePoint solution for a Company (its an Intranet). Now, the company is splitting into two and so is their intranet. Each company, of these two, from now on will have their own Intranet. So, idea is to split this Intranet (which is just a web application) into two web applications. But wait, these companies will also have some information to share in between. So, the idea is to put the shared information (Administrative stuff etc) into a separate web application. So, we have three web apps so far.

Previously, Company's intranet was managing the data of about 50 facilities in the form of Subsites. Now, according to new design, each web application will have 25 facilities each. In other words, each company will have 25 facilities. But, problem is that each facility is having large amounts of data almost 5GB+. So, its not possible for me to put the restriction quota at the site level. Although, we can put restriction on the size at SiteCollection level (as per my understanding). So, the idea so far is to create one site collection for each facility, it means we will have 25 site collections in a web applications. Navigation could be a nightmare. But, can we solve navigation problem with managed path etc?

any other suggestions/improvements will be warmly welcome and appreciated! Even your little comment may help me to improve my design ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the proposed design, you will have to manually setup the navigation (managed paths will probably not help unless you want to have something other than /sites/ in the url).

I do question why you now have to split each of the facilities into their own site collection when, before the split, subsites worked.  I would only recommend each facility be a unique site collection if you can forsee being asked to move facilities between the two new companies.

Comment: its apparent that we need to move our each facility to a unique site collection since each facility consisting for almost 10 GB + counting. Imagine if we had to keep all facilities into one site collection with one content database. Moss won't allow us to have more 100GB.

Comment: So just to clarify, you are going to be adding a new content DB to the company webapp for each facility?